# JSF и jQuery совместимость

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, java-ee, jsf

Есть JSF, в нем в есть тег:

```
<h:inputText id="email" value="#{beanBean.email}" />
```

Этот тег получается из БД. Пытаюсь получить его значение в jQuery:

```
$(document).read(function() {
    var value1 = $('#email').val();
})
```

Но не получается. Как это можно реализовать? Где моя ошибка?
Я не совсем понимаю: JSF преобразует данные в HTML или текст в конце?

Comment: Jsf преобразуется в html код на сервере и виде HTML кода отправляется пользователю. Откройте консоль браузера и посмотрите есть ли у поля #email какое-либо значение. Какой результат вы ожидаете от вашего кода?

Comment: Просто маил ввиде nik.name@mail.ru

Comment: тоесть я могу чисто теоритически использовть jsf данные как html и брать их  через jquery ?

Comment: Какой результат вы ожидаете от вашего кода? jQuery не знает какой у вас сервер. Она работает только с HTML.

Comment: Хочу взять текст и дальше положить её в функцию что посовуете ?

Comment: @elik что значит "не получается"? Как вы проверяли код на успешность выполнения? Вы HTML-код полученной страницы смотрели - там в `<input>`-е значение подставляется? И не обратили ли вы, случаем, внимание на то, что в консоли браузера вам должно было показать ошибку "метод `.read` не существует"? Ибо должно быть `.ready`.

Comment: блиииин нннннннннннннннннн

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `styleClass` для задания класса:

```
<h:someInputComponent styleClass="someClassName" />
```

который булет выглядеть в HTML как:

```
<input type="..." class="someClassName" />
```

И потом получить значение с помощью jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elementValue = $('.someClassName').val();
});
```

Comment: А можете болдее подрробно просто бросить текст hello word в этот стиль

Comment: @elik в какой именно стиль и куда бросить?)

Comment: пОКАЖИ ПРОСТО ПОЛНЫЙ XHTML КОД Я ТАК СРАЗУ ПЙОМУ

Comment: а то устал уже искать .

Comment: `<h:inputText id="email" value="#{beanBean.email}" styleClass="form-email" /> `, а в jQuery использовать селектор: `$('.form-email').val();`

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa Пасибо Браткааааааааа огромное пасибо )))понемногу пазл уже слепливается))